# Limit on numbr of excel files a folder can store

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using a folder to store the history log of events in excel format.The logging had stoped .I doubt whether it could be due to any folder limitations?

Comment: There is no limitation I know of on number of files (if there is, it must be huge). Anyway, just for organization I'd suggest splitting the files by some criterion, like year/month or so.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the limit is 65,534 for Fat32 and 4,294,967,295 for NTFS; but if you actually reach that limit there's something wrong in your application:

I would suggest you to split log files in (for example) a folder for each year or month:

```
2012
   01
     01.xls
     02.xls
     ....xls
     31.xls
   02
     01.xls
     02.xls
     ....xls
     28.xls
```

article talking about those limits:
http://ask-leo.com/is_there_a_limit_to_what_a_single_folder_or_directory_can_hold.html
or
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134(WS.10).aspx